# TypeError: <FUNCTION_NAME>.owner / .connect() is not a function on hardhat unit testing

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, unittesting, chai

**Plugin and tools used: hardhat-chai-matcher, chai, mocha**

**Issue:**

[image: prompted error on .owner() and .connect()]

Was wonder if its my environment setup wrong, so i ran other test but theyre passing just alright:

[image]

This is my test script written

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("VolcanoNFT Test", function () {
 let owner, user1, VolcanoNFTFactory, volcanoNFT;

beforeEach(async () => {
    [owner, user1] = await ethers.getSigners();
    VolcanoNFTFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("VolcanoNFT", owner.address);
    volcanoNFT = await VolcanoNFTFactory.deploy();
    await volcanoNFT.deployed();
    console.log("Deployed with:", owner.address);
    console.log("Contract Deployed to:", volcanoNFT.address);
});

describe("Deployment:", function () {
    it("Should be symbol - VOL", async function () {
        expect(await volcanoNFT.symbol()).to.equal("VOL");
    });

    it("Should be name - VolcanoNFT", async function () {
        expect(await volcanoNFT.name()).to.equal("Volcano");
    });
    
    it("Should deploy by owner address", async function () {
        expect(await volcanoNFT.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
    });
});

describe("Minting:", function () {
    it("Should add balance of NFT for user", async function () {
        const minting = await volcanoNFT.connect(user1).mint();
        expect(await volcanoNFT.balanceOf(user1.address)).to.equal(1);
    });
});
});
```

This is my solidity:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract VolcanoNFT is ERC721("Volcano", "VOL") {
 uint256 tokenId;
 constructor() {

}

function mint() public {
    _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
    tokenId++;
}

function transfer() public {
}
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your VolcanoNFT does not have an owner function

add the following import:

```
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';
```

and then inherit your contract from Ownable

```
contract VolcanoNFT is ..., Ownable {
```

read more [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control)